# How to get output of shell command while its running in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bash, shell, terminal

I know similar questions have been asked before, but none of them have answered mine. How can I get the verbose output of a shell command as its running, and interact with the command in an nstextview?

For example, lets say I'm running the command "emacs" inside of my objective c app. This shell command is a interactive app, and by piping the output I think I would only get the output of the command when its done running. What I want to do is get the output of "emacs" while its running and interact with it just like one would do if they ran the command in terminal. Is this possible? If so could you show me how to do it?

Thanks in advance